# mysql not equal not working

Tags: php, mysql

So I store all transactions in a transaction table with the following struture:

```
+----------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| debit_amount   | decimal(10,2) | YES  |     | 0.00    |                | 
| credit_amount  | decimal(10,2) | YES  |     | 0.00    |                | 
| flag           | int(11)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                | 
| date           | datetime      | YES  |     | NULL    |                | 
| id             | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment | 
+----------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Then I store the total amount of credits the user has in the "credits" row in the user table.

I am trying to figure out whether there is a mismatch in the total(debit amount + credit amount) for each user as stored in the transactions table to the number of credits stored in the user table.

basically for each user

```
 transactions.debit_amount + transactions.credit amount MUST EQUAL user.credits
```

but the does not equal operator in the mysql query does not work (especially when the transactions.total is null i.e. there is no row in the transactions table for that user):

```
SELECT s.id AS uid, s.total, s.credits
FROM (
  SELECT (sum(t.credit_amount) + sum(t.debit_amount)) AS total, t.userid, u.credits, u.id
  FROM transactions AS t
  RIGHT JOIN users AS u ON t.userid = u.id 
  GROUP BY u.id
) AS s
WHERE s.total != s.credits
```

Comment: just a thought ... may be nitpicking here but I would try to use a different name than 'transactions' just because of the word's special meaning in database contexts for transactional queries ... it won't cause errors but it might make things 1% more difficult for people ...

Comment: Just a guess: try [code]s.total <> s.credits[/code]

Comment: You say `does not work` but you give no examples of what is returned, and how that differs from what you expect...

Comment: It won't work when there's null in one of the columns as null is non-existence. Non-existence does not equal anything and non-existence + 1 is still non-existence.

Comment: @Alfabravo `!=` and `<>` are identical in their behaviour

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
select u.id, u.credits, t.total
from  users u
left join (
    select userid, sum(coalesce(credit_amount,0)) + sum(coalesce(debit_amount, 0)) as total
    from transactions
    group by userid
) t on u.id = t.userid
where coalesce(t.total, 0) <> coalesce(u.credits, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare `NULL` to a non-null value in MySQL (or at least, if you do, the result is always `NULL`).

If you can get away with it, use an `INNER JOIN` to only get users who have made a transaction. If not, use [`COALESCE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) to provide a default value of 0 when there are no transaction rows, as per Michał's answer.